# Hide multiple HTML5 Canvas elements until user selects them?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is the scenario:

I have multiple HTML5 canvases, all of which are different games.  I want to have a canvas home screen where the user can select which game they want to play.  Once selected, the selected games' canvas would appear and the user could play it.

I can make the canvases be invisible with "display: none;", but the user inputs are still activated.  For instance, one game utilizes the spacebar.  If the user clicks the spacebar on the homescreen, that canvas is still activated, even though it is hidden, and brings up an alert.

Basically, instead of "display: none;", I want to completely disable a canvas until the user selects it.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you have to manage the state of your games, if in your page it is possible to execute only a game, 1 and only 1 game instance have to be executed, and then, what can I expect from your page if more then one game accept spacebar as user input?

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I have solved it my removing the event listeners for each game until a button is clicked to play the game.  Then the event listeners are re-added for that game and removed again when the game is closed.  I appreciate the help!